# Notation unclear - Radial Basis Funtion

Tags: machine-learning, rbf

In Chapter 6 (Deep Forward Networks) on Page 193 of [Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html) they talk about the design of Hidden Units.
The Radial Basis Function is introduced as follows:
$$
h_i = exp\big{(}-\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}||W_{:,i} − x||^2\big{)}
$$

What does the colon as Index for $W$ mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the notation [page](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/notation.html), it means the $i$-th column.

$W$ is a template matrix, where the closer $x$ is to $i$-column of $W$, the bigger the value of $h_i$.